# How can I auto create ADO work item from Power BI

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, azure-devops-rest-api

Is there a way to create an Azure Devops work item (Bug) from a Power BI report. Once an user identifies an error in the Power Bi report, he would like to report it as a Bug through a link in the report. The link should create a new Bug with the screen shot of the report and additional details. Is it possible to acheive this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Power Automate](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/en-au/connectors/details/shared_visualstudioteamservices/azure-devops/) and [Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/connections/azure-devops) both have Azure DevOps connectors.  And Power BI has a Power Apps Visual and a Power Automate Visual for you to embed a Power App or kick-off a Power Automate flow from a Power BI report.

Comment: I created a Power automate visual from the report and when I dis a test run it failed with the below message. Is this a known issue . 

The execution of template action 'Apply_to_each' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerBody()?['entity']?['Power BI values']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.